# Volume bounded by two solids

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

Can somebody help me get started in the right direction for this question involving volume? The question is "Find the volume of the solid region inside the hemisphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =6, z<0$ but outside the cone $z = -\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. I converted it into polar co-ordinates, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track when trying to determine the bounds.

Comment: It will be easier if you use spherical coordinates instead of polar coordinates. The bounds for $\rho$, $\phi$, and $\theta$ will all be constants.

Comment: Always start by drawing a picture, in this case of the hemisphere and the cone, and add the various lengths. It you do this, it becomes clear that it is best to integrate over $z$. The range is $0$ to $-sqrt(3)$. The integrand is a circle with a circular hole in its centre; so its surface area is easily found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\displaystyle V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\sqrt{6}}\rho^2\sin\phi\; d\rho\; d\phi\; d\theta$